# Cannot find symbols while using abstract classes

Tags: java, overriding, abstract-class

Practicing abstract classes with shapes. The goal is to get the total area of the 3 shapes using abstract classes. So far this is what I have.

I'm not sure whether I did this part right:

```
    static double sumArea(Shape[] arr){
        // Sum up the areas of all the shapes using getArea()
        return arr.getArea();
    }
```

I keep getting error saying that it doesn't find the symbol h (height), w (width), tw (top_width). Anybody know why it's not finding these symbols?

```
public class TestShape{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Point p = new Point(1, 1);

        Shape[] arr = {
            new Rectangle(p, 3, 4),
            new Parallelogram(p, 5, 6, Math.PI/6.0),
            new Trapezoid(p, 5, 6, 2)
        };

        System.out.println("SUM_AREA = " + sumArea(arr));
    }

    static double sumArea(Shape[] arr){
        // Sum up the areas of all the shapes using getArea()
        return arr.getArea();
    }
}

class Point{
    double x, y;

    Point(){
        this(0, 0);
    }

    Point(double x, double y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "[" + x + ", " + y + "]";
    }
}

abstract class Shape{
    Shape(){

    }

    Shape(Point p){ 
        this.p = p;
    }

    public Point getPosition(){
        return p; 
    }

    public void setPosition(Point p){
        this.p = p;
    }

    // Abstract method
    public abstract double getArea(); 
}

abstract class Quadrangle extends Shape{
    protected double width, height;

    Quadrangle(Point p, double w, double h){
        this.p = p;
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
    }

    public double getWidth(){
        return w;
    }

    public double getHeight(){
        return h;
    }

    public void setWidth(double w){
        this.weight = w;
    }

    public void setHeight(double h){
        this.height = h;
    }
}

class Rectangle extends Quadrangle{
    Rectangle(Point p, double w, double h){
        this.p = p;
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
    }

    public boolean isSquare(){
        if(w == h){
            return "Error";
        }
    }

    @Override /** Return Area */
    public double getArea(){
        return w * h;
    }
}

class Parallelogram extends Quadrangle{
    protected double angle;

    Parallelogram(Point p, double w, double h, double angle){
        this.p = p;
        this.weight = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.angle = angle;
    }

    public double getAngle(){
        return angle;
    }

    public void setAngle(double a){
        this.angle = a;
    }

    @Override /** Return Area */
    public double getArea(){
        return w * h;
    }
}

class Trapezoid extends Quadrangle{
    protected double top_width;

    Trapezoid(Point p, double w, double h, double top_width){
        this.p = p;
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.top_width = top_width;
    }

    public double getTopWidth(){
        return top_width;
    }

    public void setTopWidth(double tw){
        this.top_width = tw;
    }

    @Override /** Return Area */
    public double getArea(){
        return ((w + tw) / 2) * h;
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume that you are talking about `getArea`.  The explanation is simple.  The fields that you declared in the respective classes have names `height`, `width` and `top_width` ... not `h`, `w` and `tw`.

Comment: @StephenC Doesn't the "this.width = w", etc. make it fine??

Comment: Nope.  The initialization `this.width = w` is fine, but that is an assignment, not a declaration.  The problem is that in the `getArea` you are using the wrong variable name.  Use `width` (which is equivalent to `this.width` in this case) rather than the non-existent `w` variable.  It also looks like you are missing a declaration for a field called `p` in the `Shape` class.

Comment: @StephenC Ah ok I get what you mean with the width now. But what do you mean by I didn't declare for a field called p in the shape class?

Comment: Aren't you getting a compilation error for `this.p = p;`  ??  There is no `this.p` because you have not declared a field called `p` ... in the version of `Shape` in the question.

Comment: You can't call getArea on an array. You're gonna have to call it on each element of the array and sum up the areas.

Comment: @StephenC Just figured that out. Thank you, I've fixed that now :)

Comment: @orSt Yes, I realized it wasn't the right way to do it. I'm not so sure how to call it separately so i just put it like that for now

Comment: I have a feeling that we should stop pointing out the errors.  You will learn more if you find and fix them for yourself.  N.B. Programming is a **precise** activity.  It requires attention to detail.  Program problem solving requires careful reading of the error messages and clear thinking to establish what caused them to happen.  You need to practice ....

Answer (score 1):

The names w, tw and so on only exist as parameters. When you want to access the values you save in the constructors, you have to use the left hand side name: `this.[width or whatever]`.

Also, rewrite sumArea to something like this:

```
static double sumArea(Shape[] arr){
        // Sum up the areas of all the shapes using getArea()
        double totalArea = 0;
        for (Shape shape : arr) {
                totalArea += shape.getArea();
        }
        return totalArea;
}
```